# Why can I not register for area51?

Tags: support

1. I click the "register" on area51.stackexchange.com
2. It's said "Unable to log in: No user found"

How can I login https://area51.stackexchange.com?  please

Comment: But I cannot find where the "sign up" button is, I can only find 'register' which return the same message when clicked

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot find where the "sign up" button is, I can only find 'register' which return the same message when clicked

Hello there =), please find the signup button on the top bar, here is the direct link https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=%2f

[image: signup-button-location]

When I just clicked it, it automatically logged me in  even though I never had logged in to are51 before.

Answer (score 0):

I logout from stackexchange.com and reopen area51.stackexchange.com 
now, it's all OK!
I don't known the reason, anyway, it works now

thank you all